# asp.net Jquery checkall/uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a LinkButton (below) name "Insert?", it triggers the Jquery to check all checkboxes within my DataList1. It works so far.

But I like to click on the same LinkButton and it will uncheck all checkboxes previously checked. Basically, it will toggle between checkall and uncheck all.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server"  OnClientClick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes1(this)" >Insert?</asp:LinkButton>
```

Jquery that works only checkAll, but not uncheckAll

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAllCheckboxes1(chk) {
        $('#<%=DataList1.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            //alert(this.id);
            this.checked = true; 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a link, what you can do is

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes1(chk) {
    var $checks = $('#<%=DataList1.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox");
    $checks.prop('checked', $checks.not(':checked').length != 0);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q8WZK/)

Comment: I tried this code, but it is not working when I check on the "Insert" Linkbutton, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @milacay it was a bug... I was thinking the select all was a checkbox... not fixed...

Comment: if you dont mind, can you explain this statement so I can understand it? "$checks.prop('checked', $checks.not(':checked').length != 0);" . Thanks

Comment: @milacay the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method is used to set the checked property of the checkbox where the second argument says whether it has to be checked or not, `$checks.not(':checked').length != 0` says if there is even 1 unchecked element then mark all as checked else make all unchecked

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a jQuery tag in your question, I assume you can just use this command on click of your ID element. You don't need any ASP.NET server side action for this.

**http://jsfiddle.net/879Pv/1/**

```
$("#ENameLinkBtn").click(function(){
   $(document.body).find(':checked').each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr('checked');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Response. I see your example, but is they a way to toggle checkall and uncheckAll when I click on the same LinkButton (Insert)? Also, check all the checkboxes inside the DataList as I described above?